# ImagePicker return invalid image source

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

Im using ImagePicker to pick multiple image. On android just work fine. But iOS returning.

`PlatformException (PlatformException(invalid_source, Invalid image source.`

```
ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
```

```
pickMultiImage() async {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    AppLocalizations localization = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
    try {      
      final List<XFile>? images = await _picker.pickMultiImage();
      if (images!.isNotEmpty) {
        imageFileList!.addAll(images);
      }
      setState(() {});
    } catch (e) {
      showDialogOpenPermission(
          context, localization, localization.gallery, size);
    }
  }
```

update : Checking on iOS real device just works fine. Long ago, I think just works fine on emulator :(.

** I'm prefer to test my apps by via emulator. So, If anyone here know the solution, please tell me ;)

Comment: Have you checked the permissions in pod file? sometimes emulates also blocks access for images

Comment: @Soveyyy did you solved it? I guess it's emulator bug.